# How do we find frequency of one column based off two other columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm relatively new to working with SQL and wasn't able to find any past threads to solve my question. I have three columns in a table, columns being name, customer, and location. I'd like to add an additional column determining which location is most frequent, based off name and customer (first two columns).

[image]

I have included a photo of an example where name-Jane customer-BEC in my created column would be "Texas" as that has 2 occurrences as opposed to one for California. Would there be anyway to implement this?

Comment: Would "Texas" be assigned to the row with ARC?

Comment: Did one of the answers meet your requirements? If so, please upvote and select your preferred solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want `'Texas'` on all four rows:

```
select t.Name,  t.Customer, t.Location,
      (select t2.location 
       from table1 t2
       where t2.name = t.name
       group by name, location
       order by count(*) desc
       fetch first 1 row only
      ) as most_frequent_location
from table1 t ;
```

You can also do this with analytic functions:

```
select t.Name,  t.Customer, t.Location,
       max(location) keep (dense_rank first order by location_count desc) over (partition by name) most_frequent_location
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by name, customer, location) as location_count
      from table1 t 
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f72d5e01c1ef7c4ec5d43946b3f3cda9) is a db<>fiddle.

Both of these version put `'Texas'` in all four rows.  However, each can be tweaks with minimal effort to put `'California'` in the row for ARC.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can use [aggregate function `stats_mode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/STATS_MODE.html#GUID-10BDACE0-C435-4E3F-BC50-FD1A41C0F508) to compute the most occuring value in a group.

Unfortunately it is not implemented as a window function. So one option uses an aggregate subquery, and then a join with the original table:

```
select t.*, s.top_location
from mytable t
inner join (
    select name, customer, stats_mode(location) top_location
    from mytable
    group by name, customer
) s where s.name = t.name and s.customer = t.customer
```

You could also use a correlated subquery:

```
select 
    t.*,
    (
        select stats_mode(t1.location) 
        from mytable t1 
        where t1.name = t.name and t1.customer = t.customer
    ) top_location
from mytable t
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first step is to construct a query that determines the most frequent location, which is as simple as:

```
select Name, Customer, Location, count(*)
from table1 
group by Name, Customer, Location
```

This isn't immediately useful, but the logic can be used in row_number(), which gives you a unique id for each row returned. In the query below, I'm ordering by count(*) in descending order so that the most frequent occurrence has the value 1.

Note that row_number() returns '1' to only one row.

So, now we have

```
select Name, Customer, Location, row_number() over (partition by Name, Customer order by count(*) desc) freq_name_cust
from table1 tb_
group by Name, Customer, Location
```

The final step puts it all together:

```
select tab.*, tb_.Location most_freq_location
from table1 tab
inner join 
(select Name, Customer, Location, row_number() over (partition by Name, Customer order by count(*) desc) freq_name_cust
 from table1 
 group by Name, Customer, Location) tb_
 on tb_.Name = tab.Name
  and tb_.Customer = tab.Customer
   and freq_name_cust = 1
```

[You can see how it all works in this Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/249d7/30) where I deliberately inserted rows with the same frequency for California and Texas for one of the customers for illustration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a question about understanding the concepts of a relational database. If you want that information, you would not put that in an additional column. It is calculated data over multiple columns - why would you store that in the table itself ? It is complex to code and it would also be very expensive for the database (imagine all the rows you have to calculate that value for if someone inserted a million rows)
Instead you can do one of the following

- Calculate it at runtime, as shown in the other answers
- if you want to make it more persisent, you could embed that query above in a view
- if you want to physically store the info, you could use a materialized view

Plenty of documentation on those 3 options in the official oracle documentation

Comment: Good point. A materialized view would serve you well in this case, I would say.